# Android Emulator HttpUrlConnection

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

I am writing an android app that should connect to a Web Service I wrote, but every time I try to test it on the emulator It won't work with when the app enters in the HttpUrlConnection.connect() line: see my code. There is no error shown in the logcat, but when I open the URL in the emulators browser it works. I even tried it with the '10.0.2.2' approach to connect to my localhost where the Web Service is running. Thank you in advance to anyone that can resolve this problem.

```
public JSONObject getJSON(String theUrl) throws Exception{

        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        StringBuilder jsonResults = new StringBuilder();
        URL url = new URL(theUrl);

        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.connect()
        InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());

        // Load the results into a StringBuilder
        int read;
        char[] buff = new char[1024];

        while ((read = in.read(buff)) != -1) {
            jsonResults.append(buff, 0, read);
        }
        if (conn != null) {
            conn.disconnect();
        }

        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(jsonResults.toString());
        return object;
    }
```

**UPDATE**

It's solved now by putting the method in a AsyncTask and not doing it on the main thread. Thanks to Prerak Sola!

Comment: Are you printing the stacktrace on the catch blocks?

Comment: Did you add the internet permission in manifest.xml ? 
Did you put getJson() in doInBackround method ?
can you  show us the stack trace ?

Comment: @ghassen92 yes i added the internet permission. But no, do i have to put in a doInBackground? I will try it now.

Comment: @PrerakSola Yeah I'm such an idiot -.- I let the catch block blank and did not see any exceptions. No I'm seeing the android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException. Thank u guys for helping me out :)